# Use posted data in a file that is included using file_get_contents

Tags: php, email

I am using an email template that is included using file_get_contents in my email script file.

The data from my contactform is posted to that email script. I would like to display the posted data inside the template layout. I can't echo the variables containing the posted data in the template file, so how would I do this?

file_get_contents only returns the text if I'm correct so it doesn't recognize variables right?

Comment: `ob_start(); include(...); ob_get_clean()`, basically. and yes, f_g_c is just a wrapper around fopen/fread/fclose. it doesn't "execute" anything. it just slurps in bytes.

Comment: What file do I include? Not the email template file right? I'm trying to place the variables of my posted data where I want in the email template. Echoeing it is not working (because f_g_c doesn't recognize variables as i see.

Comment: if your template is something like `Hi mom, this is <?php echo $firstname ?>`, then yes, you have to include() the file to get those variables replaced. you COULD `eval`, but that's hideously ugly and even more hideously dangerous.

Comment: @MarcB So include the mailtemplate in the mailscript? Or the mailscript in the mailtemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you CAN turn the file you request with `file_get_contents` into a PHP file to echo your data. You need to use `GET` variables when you request the file with `file_get_contents` example:

```
file_get_contents('http://somedomain.com/somefile.php?name=yourname');
```

After you do that, the requested PHP file gets executed on the server before it returns the result. so you can simply echo your data in the template at the desired place.

```
echo $_GET['name'];
```

as @marc B commented: 
This will NOT work unless you use a full-blown url, causing an http request. your "url" will cause PHP to do a LOCAL fopen and look for a file which has the literal characters ?, n, a etc.. in the filename.

Comment: This will **NOT** work unless you use a full-blown url, causing an http request. your "url" will cause php to do a LOCAL fopen and look for a file which has the literal characters `?`, `n`, `a` etc.. in the filename.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, I edited the original answer and added your comment.